# convert DateTime to string according to customCultureInfo in G((combination of date and Time) format

Tags: c#, string, datetime, cultureinfo

I have changed my system date format to Faeroese.

I want to convert DateTime to String according to customCulture with G format   (combination of date and Time)

check the below code.

```
    namespace TestDateConvertion
        {
            class Program
            {
                static void Main(string[] args)
                {
                    object value = new DateTime(2003,12,23,6,22,30);
                    DateTime dateTimeValue = (DateTime)value;
                    CultureInfo customCulture = MySettings.getCustomCulture();  
                                     //for getting custom culture in my app
                                     //in custom culture i have changed shortDateFormat according to the user preference.
                                     //value in shortDateFormat = dd/MM/yyyy




                    string result = string.Format(customCulture, "{0:G}", result);

                    Console.WriteLine(result);
                    Console.ReadLine();
                }
            }
        }
```

but i get the output with sepertators according to system DateTime not with users given format in customCulture,

i even dont find any method overloaded in `string.Format()` or `DateTime.ToString()` to do this.

If i pass CultureInfo.InvariantCulture then i cant get output in G format.

Comment: How is the culture created over here `MySettings.getCustomCulture();` ?

Comment: i have MySettings class which gives me the customCulture created by taking date format from user. the same i will be saving in customCulture.shortDateFormat

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
DateTime date1 = new DateTime(2008, 4, 10, 6, 30, 0);
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("G", DateTimeFormatInfo.InvariantInfo));
// Displays 04/10/2008 06:30:00
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("G", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("en-us")));
// Displays 4/10/2008 6:30:00 AM                        
Console.WriteLine(date1.ToString("G", CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture("nl-BE")));
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [Standard Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx#GeneralDateLongTime) "G" uses short date format (as you claim to specify). So most likely reason of using local culture separator is covered in [The "/" Custom Format Specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#dateSeparator) portion of ""Custom Date and Time Format Strings".

Since your "short date format" is `"dd/MM/yyyy"` than instead of `"/"` it will use corresponding separator from the culture info (which you are likely picking from default culture).

Escaping with `\` is covered in the [Using the escape character](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#escape) portion of the same "Custom Date and Time Format Strings" article.

So you want your `shortDateFormat = @"dd\/MM\/yyyy"` or properly specify [DateTimeSeparator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.datetimeformatinfo.dateseparator.aspx) in corresponding part of your custom `CultureInfo`.